# Transpose map in $M(2,\mathbb{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Let $T$ the transpose map $T(A)=A^t$ for $A\in M(2,\mathbb{R})$. I want to find a basis such that $T$ is diagonal. I considered $T$ as a map from $R^4\rightarrow R^4$ where $T$ can be represented by
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0& 0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&1&0\\0&1&0&0\end{pmatrix}
$$
The characteristic polynomial is $(t-1)^3(t+1)$ and by finding basis for each of the two eigenspaces I got $\{(1,0,0,0),(0,0,1,0),(0,1,0,-1),(0,1,0,1)\}$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Looks good (if I guess your basis). It may be to your advantage to also write the basis elements that you have in matrix form. everybody will then see, why some of them belong to eigenvalue $+1$ and some to $-1$ ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, you took as your basis of $M(2,\Bbb R)$ to be
$$
\mathcal B = \left\{
\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0},
\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0},
\pmatrix{0&0\\0&1},
\pmatrix{0&0\\1&0}
\right\}
$$
or something to that effect.  If so, then your representation of $T$ is correct, as is everything you've said about this transformation.

Comment: Yes, I took that basis. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If we let $E_{ij} = e_i^T e_j$, you could take the basis of eigenvectors $E_{11}, E_{22}, E_{12}+E_{21}, E_{12}-E_{21}$.

The corresponding eigenvalues are $1,1,1,-1$ from which the result follows.