# Finding eigenvalues and "eigenmatrices".

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

On the space of $2\times 2$ matrices, let $T$ be the transformation that *transposes every matrix.* Find the eigenvalues and "eigenmatrices" for $A^T =\lambda A$.

By taking determinants on the left and right hand sides in the last equation we may show that $\lambda=\pm1$. But I have no idea beyond that.

The transformation is a linear transformation all right but what will be its matrix? What is meant here by "eigenmatrices"?

Comment: See the solution outlined in [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/902000/transpose-map-in-m2-mathbbr).  Does that clarify things?

Comment: The eigenmatrices corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda = 1$ are the matrices $A$ such that $A^T = A$. The eigenmatrices corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda = -1$ are the matrices $A$ such that $A^T = -A$. Do you know what these matrices are called?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom - the eigenvalues are found to $\pm1$, but how to find their multiplicity?

Answer (score 2):

In the context of this question, an "eigenmatrix" of the transformation $T$ is a matrix $A \in M(2,\Bbb R)$ such that $A^T = \lambda A$ for some scalar $\lambda$.

So, for example, the matrix
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}
$$
is an eigenmatrix because
$$
T(A) = A^T = A = 1 \cdot A
$$

Comment: so is any symmetric or skew-symmetric $2\times2$ matrix an eigenmatrix?

Comment: @rockstar123 yes.  And, as you've indicated, there can't be any others.

Comment: Also, in order to find the multiplicities: find the dimension of the (sub-)space of symmetric matrices and the dimension of the (sub-)space of skew-symmetric matrices.

Comment: But the answer at the back of the book does not include the identity matrix as an eigenmatrix.

Comment: What does the book have for "eigenmatrices", then?

Comment: eigenvalues 1,1,1,-1. eigenmatrices [(1,0),(0,0)],[(0,1),(1,0)],[(0,0),(0,1)],[(0,-1),(1,0)].

Comment: The book is wrong.  The eigenmatrices are **the span of** [(1,0),(0,0)],[(0,1),(1,0)],[(0,0),(0,1)], and **the span of** [(0,-1),(1,0)].  The first span consists of the symmetric matrices, and the second consists of the skew-symmetric matrices.